# InputType personalizado

Tags: android, android-studio, edittext

estoy creando una App y necesito los dígitos "0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,',x"

Estoy usando inputType="TextNoSuggestions" con digits="0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,',x" pero me preguntaba si habría alguna opción mas estética.

Mi código:

```
 <EditText                    
                    android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
                    android:digits="0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,',x"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                    android:textSize="25sp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Comment: android:inputType="number"

Comment: El problema para usar number es que no puedo usar ni ' ni X. Por eso venía mi pregunta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En realidad la opción ideal es uso de la propiedad `android:digits`, definiendo los caracteres que deseas usar:

```
android:digits="0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,',x"
```

otra opción sería definiendo un `inputFilter`:

```
EditText editText = findViewById(R.id.editText);

final String blockCharacterSet = "0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,',x";

InputFilter filter = new InputFilter() {
    @Override
    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) 
        if (source != null && !blockCharacterSet.contains(("" + source))) {
            return "";
        }
        return null;
    }
};

editText.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{filter});
```

La mejor opción sería la primera ya que no tienes que escribir código simplemente agregar los caracteres permitidos en la propiedad.